# Spring doesn't add interceptors to SimpleUrlHandlerMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am adding inceprtors by exposing a bean in a following way:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

                registry.addInterceptor(cacheClearanceInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/*")
                        .order(OFFSET + 1);

                registry.addInterceptor(pageNotFoundInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/*")
                        .excludePathPatterns("/static/*").order(OFFSET + 2);

            }
        };
    }
```

I am using `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` for resolving url to handler methods. However, I don't see above interceptors added. I was expecting spring will add interceptors but it's not and request hits to handler method directly without interceptors in the middle. Do I need to call `setInteceptors` method manually to register inceptors on `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` ?